# Как с помощью тега <iframe> загрузить на свой сайт другой документ с нужными мне атрибутами class а лишние отключить?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, iframe

Моя задача такова. На моем сайте нету калькулятора но он есть на другом сайте.
с нуля я не напишу знания не позволят. по этому хочу подгрузить его с чужого сайта на свой с помощью тега iframe и отключить лишние селекторы class с помощью display:none; но у меня ничего не вышло подскажите как это реализовать?

```html
<style>

.header {display: none;}
.headertop {display: none;}
.sidebar {display: none;}


</style>


<iframe name="constr" id="InlineFrame1"  style="width:700px; height:740px;" src="http://profitability-calculator-ethereum-miners/"  scrolling="no" frameborder="0" > </iframe>
```

Comment: Боюсь не получится этого сделать. Это все равно, что вы смотрите на другой дом через бинокль с кусками пластыря на некоторых частях линз..... у линз вы закрываете ненужные части, но в реальности то дом как был весь, так и остался. Единственный вариант - пойти и снести у этого дома то, что вам не нравится.....что естесственно не получится, если вы не его владелец

Comment: Это можно достичь через прокси

Comment: Боюсь я нашел ответ =) не говорите никогда не возможно (примерчик с биноклем и кусками пластырями линзами домами  не в тему вообще надеюсь вы не хотели по умничать) http://jsfiddle.net/RwpJx/969/

Answer (score 1):

если не ошибаюсь, то политика безопасности препятствует работе с iframe загруженные с другого сайта. вот по этим ссылкам можете почитать подробнее:

1. [тут](http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy)
2. [и тут](http://www.bielousov.com/2012/iframe-same-origin-script-policy/)

хотя молва ходит в нете что как-то можно)

Comment: Можно! Но это не просто!

Comment: то что можно я не спорю, но стоят ли такие танцы с бубном достигнутого профита.. сомнительно. Как говорится постаравшись и лоб расшибить можно, а оно нам надо?

Comment: Совершенно справедливое замечание. В данном случае - это будет over engineering

Comment: Ребята снимаю вопрос ответ найден все гениально и просто =) переходим по ссылочке     http://jsfiddle.net/RwpJx/969/

Comment: И что мы видим по ссылочке?

Comment: Вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/RwpJx/  , а вот оригинальный сайт. http://www.intellicast.com/National/Radar/Current.aspx?location=USNY0850   Только необходимо знать координаты определённой области.

Answer (score -1):

вот реальный пример реализованного вопроса

```css
#outerdiv 
{ 
width:756px; 
height:496px; 
overflow:hidden; 
position:relative; 
}

#innerIframe 
{ 
position:absolute; 
top:-546px; 
left:-349px; 
width:1280px; 
height:1200px; 
}
```

```html
<div id='outerdiv'> 
<iframe src="http://www.intellicast.com/National/Radar/Current.aspx?location=USNY0850&animate=true" id='innerIframe' scrolling=no></iframe> 
</div>
```

Comment: т.е. сдвинуть iframe в пространстве это все что Вам было нужно? Сделать что-то типа бойницы в браузере?